# With Char for loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, char

My question; I want two different char value from user. For example BlockStart=a and BlockFinish=d
after then I want doing for loop 'd' to 'a'
I did BlockStart and BlockFinish properties char type and
I prepared for loop:
`{ for (char i = dto.BlockStartAlphabetical; i <= dto.BlockFinishalphabetical; i++) {} }`

but this expression don't come in for loop.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use linq in a way that helps you to build an array of characters like below :

```
var start = 'a';
var end = 'd';
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,end-start+1).Select(ix=> (char)(start+ix)).ToArray();

// result = [a,b,c,d]
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VbYVYg)

Answer (score 0):

Client entry values 'a' end 'd' but I catching look photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlT0O.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).